# Selecting an nth obs conditionally from repeated data in R

Tags: r

I have a data that shows work experience that looks something like this:

```
id = c(rep("A01", 6), rep("A02", 5))
company = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 5))

startdate = as.Date(c('2005-1-1', '2006-1-5', '2007-3-25',
                      '2008-6-1', '2009-1-1', '2011-1-3',
                      '2000-3-1', '2003-1-1', '2005-7-6', 
                      '2010-10-20', '2013-1-1'))

enddate = as.Date(c('2005-12-31', '2007-3-20', '2007-12-20',
                    '2008-10-31', '2010-12-31', '2013-1-1',
                    '2002-5-31', '2005-7-5', '2010-10-10', 
                    '2011-12-25', '2014-12-31'))

df_have = data.frame(id, company, startdate, enddate)
```

Using R, I'm currently trying to derive their work experience for the companies they've worked for in the past. What I am wanting to achieve from df_have is to group the period, if a difference between enddate to the following obs of startdate is less than 30 days, I'd like to refer to the following obs enddate.

I have included the following code to make myself a little more clearer.

```
id2 = c(rep("A01", 3), rep("A02", 3))
company2 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))

startdate2 = as.Date(c('2005-1-1', '2008-6-1', '2009-1-1',
                      '2000-3-1', '2003-1-1', '2013-1-1'))

enddate2 = as.Date(c('2007-12-20', '2008-10-31', '2013-1-1',
                    '2002-5-31', '2011-12-25', '2014-12-31'))

df_want = data.frame(id2, company2, startdate2, enddate2)
```

Could someone please give me a hand on this? Been struggling so much for the past couple of hours.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df_have %>%
  group_by(id, company) %>%
  mutate(z = (startdate - lag(enddate)) >= 30, z = cumsum(is.na(z) | z)) %>%
  group_by(id, company, z) %>%
  summarize(startdate = min(startdate), enddate = max(enddate), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   id    company     z startdate  enddate   
#   <chr> <chr>   <int> <date>     <date>    
# 1 A01   A           1 2005-01-01 2007-12-20
# 2 A01   A           2 2008-06-01 2008-10-31
# 3 A01   A           3 2009-01-01 2013-01-01
# 4 A02   B           1 2000-03-01 2002-05-31
# 5 A02   B           2 2003-01-01 2011-12-25
# 6 A02   B           3 2013-01-01 2014-12-31
```